# How to store the URL response data into the PSQL database using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, psql

I am trying to fetch data from the server and stored into a variable in python. How to pass the data from stored variable the PSQL database.

## I tried this so far

```
import json
import requests
from flask import Flask
import psycopg2
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
def data():

        new_url= "http://someurl.com"
        data = ''
        response = requests.get(new_url, data=data,headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Query-Key":"12345678" })

        responseText = response.text
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="database", user = "postgres",  password = "postgres",host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")

        print "Opened database successfully"

        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE testdb(AppID INT NOT NULL,
                                      USAGE  INT NOT NULL,
                                      AppName TEXT NOT NULL,
                                      ENVIRONMENTNAME TEXT NOT NULL);''')
        print "Table Created successfully"
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

how to pass the response variable data to the testdb table in PSQL by using Python